# Java Fraction Array

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I'm new to Object-Oriented Programming and am attempting to create methods for a Fraction class. I've created methods getNumerator(), getDenominator(), and realValue(). Now I want to create a method called createFractionArray, which returns an array of Fraction objects:

```
1/2, 1/3, ... , 1/(maxDenominator - 1) , 1/(maxDenominator)
```

I have this so far but am drawing a blank on figuring out the statements for the method. Any help on getting started would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
class Fraction {
  private int numerator, denominator;
  Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) {

    this.numerator = numerator;
    this.denominator = denominator;
  }
    int getNumerator() { return numerator; }
    int getDenominator() { return denomenator; }
    double realValue() { return (1.0 * numerator) / denominator; }
 }
```

This is the method I'd like to implement:

```java
public static Fraction[] generateFractionArray (int maxDenominator) {
}
```

Comment: You should look into [for-loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: You have the object, you just need to fill an array, how would you fill an integer array for example? `int[] int_array = new int[2]; int_array[0] = 1;` `Fraction` is just another object.

Comment: First you need to make a new array - to make one you need to know how big it will be, but you know that from maxDenominator. Then you need to fill it up, and as QBrute says, you can use a for loop to iterate over the denominators from 2 to maxDenominator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create an array of `Fraction`s from `1/2` up to `1/maxDenominator`.

First, you have to figure out how many objects there will be. For example, for `maxDenominator = 5`, you'll get fractions `[1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5]`. There are 4 fractions in total. Now, based on the first denominator and `maxDenominator`, you can find a formula to calculate the length

> length = `maxDenominator` - `minDenominator` + 1

Now all you have to do is to [create an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) with that length.

Afterwards, [iterate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) that array from `minDenominator` to `maxDenominator` inclusive and save a new `Fraction` object at each index of the array. Be careful with the indices though.

> Indices start at `0`, but your loop starts at `minDenominator`. So to get the correct index, you have to subtract `minDenominator` before using that number to access the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code to create the fractions from 1/1 to 1/maxDenominator. All you have to do is modify it to satisfy your requirments.

```
public static Fraction[] generateFractionArray (int maxDenominator)
{
    Fraction[] fractionsToReturn = new Fraction[maxDenominator];
    int numeratorForAllFractions = 1;
    for(int denom = 1; denom <= maxDenominator; denom++)
    {
        fractionsToReturn[denom - 1] = new Fraction(numeratorForAllFractions, denom);
    }

    return fractionsToReturn;
}
```

NOTE: What should you do/return when maxDenominator = 0 or = 1 or < 0.

Good Luck!

Comment: In the OP the denominators start at 2 - i.e. fraction 1/2.

Comment: hence why i stated this doesn't satisfy his requirements but gives OP plenty enough code to work with.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Thanks for the help!

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz What does the statement in the for loop do? Is that the array of Fraction objects?

Comment: @concernedButPowerless that statement goes through indices of the newly created array and sets their value (a new Fraction object). when we create the array with new Fraction[maxDenominator], all the indices contain NULL. The for loop creates all the Fraction objects so we can use them. For example, the array returned will contain your Fraction objects at every index. This means we can now use this collection of objects like so -> fractionsToReturn[3] gives us the fraction object at index 3 in the array (location 4 since array's indices start at 0). Make sense?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you for clearing it up. I'm now trying to create a method that returns the sum of the Fraction object array. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: @concernedButPowerless now that you have your objects in the array it's easy to use their methods. You can do something like fractionsToReturn[3].realValue() to get the Fraction obj's value at index 3. All there is left to do is sum the values of all your Fractions in your array into a single double variable.